# Problems with my GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I have a GridLayout 2 rows by 5 columns, and I want to make the height of the first row to something like 50, and the second row to 200. I know GridLayout creates equally-sized cells, so this didn't work out. I also tried splitting the two rows into two GridLayouts setting their desired heights and adding them to a FlowLayout, but the columns didn't align the way I wanted it to. My code went something like this:

```
row1.setSize(WIDTH, 50); //GridLayout
row2.setSize(WIDTH, 200); //GridLayout
panel.add(row1);
panel.add(row2); //panel is a FlowLayout
```

The columns aligning are very important and I can't seem to get this right.

Comment: In the question you have mentioned to make the HEIGHT 50 & 200. But in code you have set the WIDTH. Which one you want to set, make it clear.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention WIDTH is an arbitrary variable here, only used to show that I want the same width for both rows, but different heights, hence the 50 height set for row1 and the 200 height for row2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look into GridBagLayout. Although, almost everyone I've talked seems to dislike it. I like it, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with a GridLayout.

You should be able to use either a GridBagLayout or a SpringLayout. Check out the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for some examples to get you started.

Also you don't add individual rows to the layout. You need to add all 10 components individually to the same panel using whatever layout manager you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Each cell in a GridLayout is exactly the same size, so you'll have to use a different layout manager, e.g. GridBagLayout.

Comment: -1, duplicate answer. GridBagLayout was suggested 40 minutes earlier. The poster already stated they knew a GridLayout created "equally-sized cells", so there was no need to repeat this either.